# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:db2://URL/Database - pom.xml

Tags: soapui, maven, groovy

In my Soapui project I am connecting Db2 for validation Groovy step. This seems to be working. When I run pop.xml with required dependency, its giving the following error:

`java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:db2://URL/Database`

Any suggestions as to why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Finally issue got resolved , i have changed my pom.xml file

Answer (score 2):

It cant find your driver.  You need to download the driver from here:  https://www.soapui.org/jdbc/reference/jdbc-drivers.html

and then save the .jar file to your c:\Program Files\SmartBear\Soapui5.x\lib folder.  Then you should be ok.

Comment: Hi I have required jar [db2jcc4-1.0] in \\SoapUI\5.0.0\bin\ext folder and its working while running the TestSuite in soapui free version. while running the project from pom.xml , its giving error. I have placed the same jar file in Projectpath\ext folder where pom.xml is running.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a funny where any test in SoapUI would fail until I had tried test connection from the environments and connections screen.

Once I do that, all tests with jdbc are fine.

It's as though I needed to 'blow the air out of the pipe'.